# Count the number of files selected for upload within multiple file fields

Tags: php

I've wrote a script where the user can select to upload more than one image to a form. I'm preventing the user from submitting the form until all of the file fields that have been added actually contain files for upload.

**EG:**

The user has three file fields to fill in, therefore three files must be ready for submission to the database.

I'm using the same id on each of the file upload fields. When I use `print_r($_FILES);` it returns me an array. If I browse for a file in the first file field, and leave another two blank, it will state that the array object for [1] and [2] are blank, however [0] will obviously have a name, type, size etc as it exists.

How would I go about making sure that all of the file fields are actually filled in using PHP?

Thanks in advance, Rich

Here are my efforts so far:

```
$imgName1 = $_FILES['upload1']['name'];
$imgTmp1 = $_FILES['upload1']['tmp_name'];
$imgType1 = $_FILES['upload1']['type'];
$imgSize1 = $_FILES['upload1']['size'];

print_r($_FILES);

if(!$imgTmp1){
echo "<span class='error'>You need to include at least one image with this article.</span>";    
exit();

} else {

$fileCount=($_FILES['upload1']['name']); // My attempt to count that the file fields are all filled in

$cnt = $_POST['cnt']; // This is the number of file fields that currently exist

echo "<br/>";

echo count($fileCount);
if($cnt != $fileCount){
echo "<span class='error'>You have not uploaded all of your files.</span>";
exit();
}

// etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect upload checking. The presence something in $_FILES doesn't mean that file uploaded. A failed upload will STILL create $_FILES entries.

You need to check for BOTH the presence of the $_FILES entry, and its `error` parameter:

```
if (isset($_FILES['upload1'])) { 
    if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       ... file was successfully uploaded
    } else {
       ... upload failed
    }
} else {
    ... no file upload was even attempted
}
```